# Relative wind velocity explanation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, vectors

I am having trouble understanding the reasoning behind the solution in this *Irodov General Physics* problem:

> **problem 1.6.)** A ship moves along the equator to the east with velocity
>   $v_0=30\;km/h$. The southeastern wind blows at an angle $\theta=60°$ to the equator with velocity $v=15\;km/h$. Find the wind velocity $v'$ relative to the ship and the angle $\theta'$ between the equator and the wind direction in the reference frame fixed to the ship.

My calculations:

[image: My diagram]

After drawing the initial diagram I consider that in order for the wind direction to be relative to the boat, I need to subtract the boat vector from the wind vector.

In my diagram I have repositioned the boat vector to be subtracted from the wind vector and using trigonometry I solve as follows:

First the *cosine law* to determine the magnitude

The magnitude = $\sqrt{30^2 + 15^2 - 2\cdot 15\cdot 30\cdot \cos{60}}$

= $\sqrt{675} \approx 25.98$

Then for the angle I can use *sine law*

$\frac{sin(\theta)}{30\frac {km}{h}} = \frac{sin(60)}{\sqrt{675}}$

$\theta= \arcsin{\frac{30\frac {km}{h}\cdot sin(60)}{\sqrt{675}}}$

$\theta = 90°$

The answer I get is therefore that the wind, in reference to the boat (as felt by the people standing on the boat), is approx $26\:km/h$ at an angle of $60°$ South of West (in relation to the equator).

However the answer given in the solutions is always that the approximate speed of the wind is $40\:km/h$ and the angle is approx $19°$.

I have looked at the solutions and I think the best explanation is given in the following diagrams obtained from [link #3](http://irodovsolutionsmechanics.blogspot.in/2007/07/problem-16.html):

[image: Diagram]

[image: Formula]

I do not understand, however, why he is using $\cos{(\pi +\theta)}$. I want to understand why my solution is incorrect and yields a different answer. What is my mistake and what is the proper intuition for understanding this problem if I have done so incorrectly?

Solutions I have viewed:

1. [This Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lewt41RX3lQ)
2. [This online blog](http://irodovphysicssolutionrks.blogspot.in/2012/06/16.html)
3. [This online blog](http://irodovsolutionsmechanics.blogspot.in/2007/07/problem-16.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A South Easterly wind comes **from** the South East your diagram seems to show a North Easterly wind. As the ship is steaming into the wind the apparent velocity should be greater than the true velocity.

Comment: Sorry this answer is so short, but I'm lying in bed using my iPad, I will flesh it out tomorrow morning.

Comment: I am banging my head on the wall... I understand my mistake. I will give you the answer once you decide to write it--a more complete solution that is.

Comment: The calculations all work out according to the solution, but, just a thought, why do the diagrams seem to indicate the wind is blowing in the South Eastern direction as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to the I.E.IRODOV (Problems in General Physics) question number 1.6 (KINEMATICS)

South-Eastern winds don't go towards South-East, in fact it's the complete opposite, they originate from South-East and go towards North-West.

So, if you were to reverse the direction of the wind vector, the solution would be correct and so will be the answer obtained by you.